# Plotting a parabola in two segments

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'd like to know how to plot the following function, defined by the red lines:

[image]

I've previously plotted a rectangle, which is easier because I just draw lines between the different points and that's it, but in this one I don't know how to join the extreme points (1, 1) and (5, 1) with the function y = sqrt(x) instead of a straight line.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: you can draw any curve by approximating it with short bits of straight line.

Comment: Did none of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is what you want to achieve. The keypoint being I guess, you were not sure that how to calculate the y-coordinate value. That is, when I plote the vertical red line, for the y coordinate, I input sqrt(5). This you see in the 9th line in the code snippet below.

```
clear;
clc;
figure(1);
clf;
x=0:0.01:6;
y=sqrt(x);
plot(x,y, 'LineWidth',2);
hold on;
plot([1 5], [1 1], 'r', 'LineWidth',2);
plot([5 5], [sqrt(5) 1], 'r', 'LineWidth',2);
grid on;
xlim([-2 6]);
ylim([-1 3]);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('y=sqrt(x)');

text(1.01, 0.85,'(1; 1)', 'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'FontSize', 12, ...
'FontWeight', 'bold')
text(5.01, 0.85,'(5; 1)', 'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'FontSize', 12, ...
    'FontWeight', 'bold')


text(2,0.5+sqrt(2),'\downarrow y=\surd x', 'HorizontalAlignment','left' ...
, 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this short piece of code:

```
y = @(x) sqrt(x);
fplot(y,[0 6])% draw the function between x=0 to x=6
hold on
fplot(y,[1 5],'r') % draw the red part of the function
plot([1 5;5 5],[1 1;1 y(5)],'r') % draw the straight lines
hold off
grid on
xlim([-2 6])
ylim([-1 3])
```

[image: sqrt (x)]